# how to use use different line tickness using glBufferData

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I have this code, that isn't working I don't know why, I think it should, but it seem that the fir buffer data is replaced with the second one.
What I want to achieve is the first with line thickness different than the other,

```
vector<float> vert={-.4,.2,-.2,.6};
vector<float> vert1={-.9,.9,-.2,.6};

glGenBuffers(1, &pbo1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pbo1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert1.size()*sizeof(float), &vert1[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &pbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert.size()*sizeof(float), &vert[0],  GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


void draw{
glUseProgram(program);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pbo);
glLineWidth(8.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0,  qtv );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pbo1);
glLineWidth(1.0f);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0,  qtv );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)0, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

These functions do not affect the state of the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Indeed, merely binding a buffer to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` will not *in any way* affect what gets rendered.

If you're not going to use [VAOs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/VAO) to encapsulate this state, then you need to call both of those functions after binding the buffer to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, but before rendering. That is, you need to do that as part of the `draw` function.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to draw one of the VBOs both inside one VAO, with line thickness different.

Comment: @user2170324 : Try different line widths, some implementations won't support higher line width values